# German Umlaute in Translation in abp.io

Tags: abp

io Community,

I am using the build in translation. Within my json I have following translation:

[image]

Within my razor page I use it here:

[image]

However, the output is:
[image]

**How can I avoid this (UTF?) problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your de.json file as UTF-8

Check out:

https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/4626
https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/2180#issuecomment-554852256